# How to access item data from dxList ,Devextreme Mobile

Tags: mobile, checkbox, devextreme, phonejs

HTML

```
<div data-bind="dxList: { dataSource: dataSource }">
  <div data-options="dxTemplate : { name: 'item' } " >
    <div class="list-item" data-bind="text: name"></div>
    <div data-bind="dxCheckBox: {value: check }"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div data-bind="text: 'Save', click: save"></div>
```

Javascript

```
var dataSource = ko.observableArray([]);
dataSource.push({ name: "name1", check: true });
dataSource.push({ name: "name2", check: false });
save: function () {

}
```

How to get 'name' and 'check' values inside save function,Devextreme mobile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just can use the `dataSource` array.

```
var save = function () {
    var items = dataSource();

    console.log(items[0].name + " - " + items[0].check());
    console.log(items[1].name + " - " + items[1].check());
};
```

If you want to get only checked items, you can use the [jQuery.grep](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/) function to filter data.

```
var items = $.grep(dataSource(), function(item){
    return item.check() === true;
});
```

Also, I suggest you use the [ko.observable()](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html) to define the `check` field of items. It allows you to track changes of the `check` field.

http://jsfiddle.net/d4t1pqby/3/